# How to overlay image over div

Tags: html

I have a assesment from my professor where i need to create a div square and overlay an image over it. i have tried to use Positioning, indexing and i tried to play with the margins but i couldnt figure out how to overlay my image over the div.

can someone help me please?
assignment from professor:
[image: assignment from professor]

my code result:

[image: my code result]

my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body>* {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}

video {
  max-height: 425px;
}

.square {
  width: 75%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 10px dashed rgb(10, 241, 164);
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 66%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0, 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<img src="/images/100km.png" alt="100km bord">
```

Comment: Have you tried positioning the child using top, left, right, bottom properties?

Comment: yes, i tried that but i couldnt get it on top of each other, sometimes the div just dissapeared

Comment: @klaasvanburen10 have you tried using positions like "relative" and "absolute". For the overlay you can also give opacity to an class.

Comment: yes i also tried relative and absolute

Comment: I put an aswer for you, you need to switch the two positions arround. Then you can start doing your positions using margins or top/bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute positioned element needs to be inside the relative positioned element. Otherwise it'll be positioned in relation to root element.

In this case your image needs to be inside the `<div>`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body>* {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 10px dashed rgb(10, 241, 164);
  border-radius: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 66%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0, 5;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="100km bord">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue, you put absolute on the image, but the but the squire needs to be absolute and the image needs to be relative.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Assignment-E1</title>
        <style>
          body {
            margin: 0;
          }
    
          body > * {
            max-width: 250px;
            max-height: 250px;
          }
    
          video {
            max-height: 425px;
          }
    
          .square{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: blue;
            border: 10px dashed rgb(10, 241, 164);
            border-radius: 50px;
            position: absolute;
          }
    
          img{
            width: 66%;
            margin-right: -100%;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            opacity: 0,5;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <img src="/images/100km.png" alt="100km bord">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. I created a main container to hold both the square and image and give it a class container. Then used different positions to set it match what you have

```
//HTML
<div class='container'> 
<div class="square"></div>
        <img src="/images/100km.png" alt="100km bord">
</div>
```

CSS

You should adjust the opacity between 0 and 1 . The image is in the bottom right corner to match what you want

```
    .container{
        position: relative;
    }

      .square{
        width: 75%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
        border: 10px dashed rgb(10, 241, 164);
        border-radius: 50px;
        position: relative;
      }

      img{
        width: 66%;
        margin-right: -100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
         top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body>* {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 10px dashed rgb(10, 241, 164);
  border-radius: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 66%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0, 5;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="100km bord">
</div>
```